# Print barcode using thermal printer Android

Tags: android, printing, thermal-printer

I was able to print text but when it comes to barcode it not showing or just showing irregular text.

**Here is my source code**

```
//barcode 128
                byte[] formats  = {(byte) 0x1d, (byte) 0x6b, (byte) 0x73,(byte) 0x0d};
                byte[] contents = content.getBytes();

                byte[] bytes    = new byte[formats.length + contents.length];

                System.arraycopy(formats, 0, bytes, 0, formats.length );
                System.arraycopy(contents, 0, bytes, formats.length, contents.length);


                usbCtrl.sendByte(bytes, dev);

                usbCtrl.sendByte(LineFeed(), dev);
```

but the result barcode is not showing, am i missing something

Please help me

**EDIT**

I found the ESC/POS code :

> GS  k  m  d1...dk  NUL or GS  k m n d1...d k

But when I try this, still got same result

Comment: check if your printer support barcode print or not.. between which thermal printer you are using

Comment: I using yongli model: POS-5890H USB paper width 58 mm, 
I saw on specification its support barcode

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `GS k` POS code has two versions (as you already discovered):

```
GS k    - print one dimensional barcode  
   m    - barcode mode selector  
   [d]k - data bytes
   NUL  - terminator
```

This version works only for pure ASCII data since it uses a `0x00` (NUL) as terminator.

```
GS k    - print one dimensional barcode  
   m    - barcode mode selector  
   n    - content length in bytes
   [d]k - data bytes
```

This version uses an additional length byte `n` to indicate the data part (it's also only suitable for certain codings including `CODE128`).

Your code has a stray `0x0d` in the command bytes and may also be using the wrong format.

If you plan to print pure ASCII data format the command like this:

```
byte[] formats  = {(byte) 0x1d, (byte) 0x6b, (byte) 0x49};
byte[] contents = content.getBytes();

byte[] bytes    = new byte[formats.length + contents.length + 1];

System.arraycopy(formats, 0, bytes, 0, formats.length );
System.arraycopy(contents, 0, bytes, formats.length, contents.length);

// add a terminating NULL
bytes[formats.length + contents.length] = (byte) 0x00;
```

Or the more secure version since it also has the expected data length:

```
byte[] contents = content.getBytes();
// include the content length after the mode selector (0x49)
byte[] formats  = {(byte) 0x1d, (byte) 0x6b, (byte) 0x49, (byte)content.length};

byte[] bytes    = new byte[formats.length + contents.length];

System.arraycopy(formats, 0, bytes, 0, formats.length );
System.arraycopy(contents, 0, bytes, formats.length, contents.length);
```

If *neither* of the two work then your printer may simply not support `CODE128`.

The 5890 is a common enough specification and there are lots of cheap "drop-in" replacements on the market which leave out the more complex barcode implementations and only include simple codings like `EAN8`, `EAN13` etc.

Comment: ok tomorrow I will try your code hope it's working, thanks anyway

Comment: I'm back at work in a few hours - I'll double check with our own CODE128 functions :)

Comment: OK, minor edit: it's hex 0x49 (decimal 73) for CODE128 printout.

Comment: So here the result :You're code is working fine on printer type ZJ-5802DD Bluetooth previously not working too but now it can, so I think my USB printer is not support to print barcode, anyway very big thanks for help me a lot and clear explanation, I'm so glad when your code working, maybe I must change my printer USB :D